# Nginx Configuration

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am trying to setup nginx web server for my web application.
Below are the URL's I want

```
www.example.com           -----> /var/www/html
www.example.com/backend/  -----> /var/www/app/backend/www
www.example.com/frontend/ -----> /var/www/app/frontend/www
```

I am able to get /var/www/html to server me proper php file for example.com, but the other two I am not able to get them working.

My application is built on yii and I have used this as my base https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBackboneBoilerplate

There is a rewrite to remove index.php from the url

When I go to www.example.com/backend it takes me to the index.php but I have rewrites for url which make the link as such www.example.com/backend/site/login

and in the error logs show up like such

`"/var/www/app/backend/www/site/login/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 114.143.183.171, server: example.com, request: "GET /backend/site/login/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"`

Below is the snippte of my conf

```
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";
location / {
           root /var/www/html/;
           index $yii_bootstrap;
}
location /backend {
         alias /var/www/app/backend/www;
         index $yii_bootstrap;
}
location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
                set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        # connect to a unix domain-socket:
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        # This file is present on Debian systems..
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Please help me resolve this issue? I have tried to understand but cant find where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 request = 1 location

You will need to duplicate your regex location so one is found per prefix location you have. That is the most efficient way of doing it.

Do not be frightened of copy-pasting! those few extra bytes in configuration will make nginx configuration more readable, scalable and running more efficiently.

```
location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~* \.php$ {
        [...]
    }
}

location /backend/ {
    alias /var/www/html/backend/www/;
    location ~* \.php$ {
        [...]
    }
}

location /frontend/ {
    alias /var/www/html/frontend/www/;
    location ~* \.php$ {
        [...]
    }
}
```